# Ответ 403 если в POST есть слово "having"

Tags: php, http

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, может кто сталкивался.

Есть простейшая форма:

1 поле text
2 поле textarea

Которая возвращает 403 Forbidden если в конце текста в textarea есть слово "having".

Причем 403 отдает сервер, до скрипта даже дело не доходит.
На сервере стоит  Cpanel, PHP 5.6
ModSecurity не установлено.
Какая то магия...

Comment: *"ModSecurity не установлено."* -- [а по симптомам не похоже](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32983206/2076787). Даже если это не он, это всё равно какая-то наколенная система предотвращения вторжений, которая предотвращает ещё и посещения, и её надо найти.

Comment: Спасибо! У меня тоже подозрение на  что-то похожее ModSecurity.